# Can i use more than one map v3 in one applicaton

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

am working on an android application using map v3 in a webview. I tried adding another map to my second activity, haven used one map on the first activity but the second map is not loading. Actually the second map I want to use for direction services but it doesn't load. I need your assistance.

Comment: off course you can use multiple maps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly set up your Map? Be sure to call a Method like this in you OnCreate() Method:

```
     private void setUpMap(){
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maptwo))
               .getMap();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.new LatLng(47.99832, 7.87443),14)); }
```

in your XML-File you have to set up an ID for your Map Fragment

```
      android:id="@id/maptwo"
```

I hope my answer was a bit useful for your issue.

Comment: thanks but am using map v3 in android webview with JavaScript api.